# How do you make FindFirstFile open a subdirectory of the path you gave it?

Tags: c++

I want to go through all the subdirectories of a directory to find all **.snt** files. But FindFirstFile and FindNextFile only search through the given directory, not through its subdirectories.

Specifically I'm searching through all the subfolders of the **sounds** folder in the path F:\Program Files (x86)\Amnesia\sounds\
I tried passing `F:\\Program Files (x86)\\Amnesia\\sounds\\*\\*.snt` to FindFirstFile but it returns garbage. What's the correct way to do this?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    char  path[100]="F:\\Program Files (x86)\\Amnesia\\sounds\\*\\*.snt";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    hFind = FindFirstFile(path, &FindFileData);
    printf("The first file found is %s\n",FindFileData.cFileName);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `<iostream.h>` ? That's been replaced about 15 years ago by plain `<iostream>`. But you're using `printf` so why are you even including `<iostream.h>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 'manual' recursion.

Following there is an idea for recursion. What is missing is file detection based on extension.

```
void file_search_rec(const char *folder)
{
    char path[MAX_PATH] ;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;

    strcpy(path, folder) ;
    strcat(path, "\\*") ;
    FindFirstFile(path, &FindFileData) ;
    if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
    {
        char subpath[MAX_PATH] ;
        strcpy(subpath, folder) ;
        strcat(subpath, FindFileData.cFileName) ;
        // here make the recursive call on subpath
        file_search_rec(subpath) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is Depth-First, not the most efficient method. A more efficient method is to have a stack of directories which you've discovered but not scanned. Start by pushing the root directory. While the stack isn't empty, take a directory from the top of the stack, scan that, and if you encounter a subdirectory you push that on the stack (instead of immediately recursing). This means you scan only one dir at a time.

Comment: The strategy above its easier to implement if one moves to C++ using std::string instead of plain char(s)

Comment: dayyum. you'd think they would have made a function for it by now

Comment: @ZazaZaza: They did - it's in the Boost library. Well, not a function but a class: [`boost::recursive_directory_iterator`](http://thisthread.blogspot.nl/2011/07/using-recursivedirectoryiterator.html)

Comment: FindClose is missing in the example, MSDN: "When the search handle is no longer needed, close it by using the FindClose function". HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(path, &FindFileData); if(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { ....; FindClose(hFind); }